# creating rake task to delete messages older than x days

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How should I go about creating a rake task for deleting all messages that are older than 30 days? I have the mailboxer gem.

I tried to test it by doing:

```
desc "Remove message older than a day"
task :remove_old_notifications => :environment do
Notification.delete_all ["created_at < ?", 1.day.ago]
end
```

However it does take any action. I have the file inside /lib/tasks

Comment: What did you call the file? How did you try to execute it?

Comment: Is your rake task not executing or it is getting executed but records are not getting deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in notifications.rake file or something like that (extension need to be .rake). After that it'll be visible in

```
rake -T
```

output and you'll can run it using

```
rake remove_old_notifications
```